# IF ELSE condition with Selenium (C#) when an element is not present

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am using Selenium with C# on NUNit framework and I am trying to put an Conditional statement looking for an element (banner to be specific). I already have a piece of code to click that banner and go forward in my test flow.

Now, I am after a condition that IF that banner is not present THEN user should have to perform additional steps to set the banner and proceed.

So, I want my IF to check not present condition to execute that piece of code otherwise will skip it.

```
var banner = FindElement(By.Id("bannerId"));
IF ( checking if above element not present)
{ execute set of steps to set the banner }
ELSE 
{
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
 wait2.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("bannerId")));

banner.Click();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

I hope I was able to explain my problem and will appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you clarify the following? you mentioned _to check not present condition to execute that piece of code otherwise will **skip** it_ but in your code trial instead you have `banner.Click()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :

```
public bool IsElementVisible(IWebElement element)
{
    return element.Displayed && element.Enabled;
}

IF(IsElementVisible(banner) == false)
{ execute set of steps to set the banner }
```

Comment: The above piece of code is already within a 'public static void' method. So, I guess can't initiate a public bool within that

Comment: No issue , you can create a method IsElementVisible in your utils class.

Comment: Super, I have now created a new method and will call in my IF ELSE statement. Let's see how it works after I have figured out the code for IF bit.  Thanks heaps..!!

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? The question didn't mention the element was hidden. What if the element doesn't exist at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the try and catch,

```
try
{
    var banner = FindElement(By.Id("bannerId"));
    IF ( checking if above element not present)
    { execute set of steps to set the banner }
    ELSE 
    {
       WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
       wait2.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("bannerId")));

       banner.Click();
       Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //check what will be the return message from ex.Message
    //and from here you could add a logic what would be your next step.
}
```

Comment: Can you please suggest how should I check for the IF condition

Answer (score 0):

I have validated your code. I can see some mistakes. Please find the suggestions below:

1. The line of your code :

   **var banner = FindElement(By.Id("bannerId"));** will throw a "**NoSuchElementException**" and the **if** statement on the next line will not be executed. Hence, the simplest option will be to use try and catch where you are finding the element and skip the **if** block.

Your code snippet can be:

```
 try   
{
var banner = FindElement(By.Id("bannerId"));
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
wait2.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("bannerId")));
banner.Click();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
 catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
{
  //Give the appropriate message
}
```

2. If you want to follow the approach you have mentioned in your code then please try the code snippet below. You will have to store the elements in the List and check the list size. If the size of the list is not zero, then you can click the banner else display the appropriate message.

Second code snippet:

```
IList<IWebElement> banner = driver.FindElements(By.Id("bannerId"));
IF ( list size is zero)
 { execute set of steps to set the banner }
 ELSE 
{
 WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
wait2.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("bannerId")));
//Click on the first element of the list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FindElements` instead, it will prevent the exception and you can check the size of the returned collection to check if the banner exists

```
IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.Id("bannerId")).ToList();
if(elements.Count == 0)
{
    do something
}
else 
{
    //do something with the banner at elements[0]
    wait2.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(elements[0])).Click();
}
```